# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ... at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$pocasie = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pocasie");
mysqli_query($pocasie, "UPDATE `pocasie` SET `aktualnateplota`=$aktualna_teplota, `relativnavlhkost`=$relativna_vlhkost, `smervetra`=$smer_vetra, `rychlostvetra`=$rychlost_vetra, `barometrickytlak`=$barometricky_tlak, `rosnybod`=$rosny_bod, `pocitovateplota`=$pocitova_teplota, `ikonka`=$ikonka, `ikonkaurl`=$ikonka_url WHERE id=1") or die (mysqli_error($pocasie));
```

Can anyone help me? I get error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `smervetra`=160, `rychlostvetra`=7, `barometrickytlak`=1024, `rosnybod`=5, `poc' at line 1

db and table name is pocasie

Comment: Use single quotes for your variables.

Comment: MySQLi supports prepared queries. Try using those... [see the php doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclose values in (`''`)....change

```
 `aktualnateplota`=$aktualna_teplota
```

to

```
 `aktualnateplota`= '$aktualna_teplota' .../* notice single quoted value here */
```

In

```
mysqli_query($pocasie, "UPDATE `pocasie` SET `aktualnateplota`='$aktualna_teplota', `relativnavlhkost`=$relativna_vlhkost, `smervetra`='$smer_vetra', `rychlostvetra`='$rychlost_vetra', `barometrickytlak`='$barometricky_tlak', `rosnybod`='$rosny_bod', `pocitovateplota`='$pocitova_teplota', `ikonka`='$ikonka', `ikonkaurl`='$ikonka_url' WHERE id=1") or die (mysqli_error($pocasie));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this single quote (') to your variables. Your query should look like this:

```
mysqli_query($pocasie, "UPDATE `pocasie` SET `aktualnateplota`='$aktualna_teplota', `relativnavlhkost`='$relativna_vlhkost', `smervetra`='$smer_vetra', `rychlostvetra`='$rychlost_vetra', `barometrickytlak`='$barometricky_tlak', `rosnybod`='$rosny_bod', `pocitovateplota`='$pocitova_teplota', `ikonka`='$ikonka', `ikonkaurl`='$ikonka_url' WHERE `id`='1'");
```

Comment: the backticks are fine